# Convert tuple to number in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have this list of tuples:

```
<TupleList>
    <Tuple>1.1.1</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.1.2</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.1.3</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.2.1</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.2.2.1</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.2.2.2</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.2.2.3</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.2.3</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.3.1</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.3.2</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.3.3</Tuple>
</TupleList>
```

Now, let's say I want to process each one into a number like this:

```
1001001000
1001002000
1001003000
1002001000
1002002001
1002002002
1002002003
1002003000
1003001000
1003002000
1003003000
```

In a normal programming language, I'd likely split each tuple by the '.' and then use the maximum array count returned to determine my overal size. I'd then (probably) loop through each digit of each tuple multiplying that digit by 1000^(max-p), where p is my current position in the array.

All that said, is there a way for me to do something like this in XSL? Not using C# or any other embedded language as I don't know if the tool I'm working with will let me.

Is this even possible in straight XSL without resorting to a more advanced programming language?

As always, any and all clues greatly appreciated.

Comment: To do this in "straight XSL", it would be convenient to have "straight XML" as the input - i.e. have each digit in a separate element, child of `<Tuple>`. You could do this as the first step of the transformation - but it adds complexity and there might be a more straightforward way. Which XSLT version can you use?

Comment: I don't have control of the XML I'm working with. If I did, I wouldn't need to ask this question. I'd just do as you suggest... :) And for XSLT? 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible in straight XSL

It is possible, though it's not quite simple, considering that XSLT does not even have built-in exponentiation. Still, you could try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="max">
    <xsl:for-each select="/TupleList/Tuple">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(translate(., '0123456789', ''))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(translate(., '0123456789', ''))"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <NumberList>
        <xsl:for-each select="TupleList/Tuple">
            <xsl:call-template name="numerize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </NumberList>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="numerize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter">.</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="position" select="$max"/>
    <xsl:param name="multiplier">
        <xsl:call-template name="power">
            <xsl:with-param name="base" select="1000"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="exponent" select="$position"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="numerize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="result" select="$result + substring-before($text, $delimiter) * $multiplier"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <number>
                <xsl:value-of select="$result + $text * $multiplier"/>
            </number>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="power">
    <xsl:param name="base"/>
    <xsl:param name="exponent"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$exponent = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$exponent > 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="power">
            <xsl:with-param name="base" select="$base"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="exponent" select="$exponent - 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="result" select="$base * $result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$base * $result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following **test input**:

```
<TupleList>
    <Tuple>0</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.23</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.23.456</Tuple>
    <Tuple>1.23.456.78</Tuple>
</TupleList>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NumberList>
   <number>0</number>
   <number>1000000000</number>
   <number>1023000000</number>
   <number>1023456000</number>
   <number>1023456078</number>
</NumberList>
```

--
I believe the assumption regarding tuple elements being integers in the range of 0..999 is self-evident.

Comment: Wow. I'm impressed. :) I really expected an answer like "this is not easily done" over an actual implementation. Thank you so very much for this. I will test this later when I have a chance and if it works with my code, I'll definitely mark it as an answer. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Alright, I finally got a chance to test this... and I'm marking this as the answer with one caveat. :) On XSLFiddle.net I get the result above, on XSLTransform.net I get an answer that is slightly off... obviously a difference in engines. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: @EDanaII "*on XSLTransform.net I get an answer that is slightly off...*"  Only if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor, I think. --  "*I'm marking this as the answer*" Uhm... try again?

Comment: Nope. :) It worked fine on XSLFiddle. That's good enough for me.

Comment: @EDanaII I meant try again marking this as an answer... :)

Comment: Oh, my bad. I upvoted; clicked on the wrong thing. Corrected. :)